# how can i retrieve values by clicking specific information

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a set of information of few employees and i want to show their information by clicking specific employees.

```
<md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-z1" layout="column" style="background-color:white; margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:30px;" ng-controller="listController">
  <div layout="row" ng-repeat="x in names" style="border-bottom:1px solid #d5d5d5;" ng-click="showAdvanced($event,$index)"> 
     <div class="" layout="column" style="">
        <center class="list-title">
           <img src="/app/img/adnan.jpg" alt="contact image" style="border-radius:50%; height:30px; width:30px; ">
            <span style="margin-left: 8px;font-weight: bold;">{{ x.id }}</span>
           </center>
         </div>

         <div class="" layout="column" style="margin:0px auto;text-align: justify;"> 
           <label for="email" class="list-email" id="popupContainer">{{ x.name }}</label>                            
         </div>

         <div class="" layout="column">
           <label for="phone-no" class="list-phn-no">{{ x.timeStamp }}</label>
         </div>       
       </div>          

 </md-whiteframe>
```

This is my index.html page and when the user will click then row a tab will open which i have already done and there will show their informations.Based on the employees the information will change. But my question is how can i retrieve user by clicking only.

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Mango (Fruit)">
 <form>
  <md-dialog-content style="max-width:800px;max-height:810px; color:green;" ng-controller="listController">
   <div>
    <p>
      The mango is a juicy stone fruit belonging to the genus Mangifera, consisting of numerous tropical fruiting trees, cultivated mostly for edible fruit. The majority of these species are found in nature as wild mangoes. They all belong to the flowering plant family Anacardiaceae. The mango is native to South and Southeast Asia, from where it has been distributed worldwide to become one of the most cultivated fruits in the tropics.
    </p>
    <img style="margin: auto; max-width: 100px;" alt="Lush mango tree" src="/app/img/adnan.jpg">
    <p>
      The highest concentration of Mangifera genus is in the western part of Malesia (Sumatra, Java and Borneo) and in Burma and India. While other Mangifera species (e.g. horse mango, M. foetida) are also grown on a more localized basis, Mangifera indica&mdash;the "common mango" or "Indian mango"&mdash;is the only mango tree commonly cultivated in many tropical and subtropical regions.
    </p>
    <p>
      It originated in Indian subcontinent (present day India and Pakistan) and Burma. It is the national fruit of India, Pakistan, and the Philippines, and the national tree of Bangladesh. In several cultures, its fruit and leaves are ritually used as floral decorations at weddings, public celebrations, and religious ceremonies.
    </p>
  </div>
 </md-dialog-content>
```

This is the page where i want to show the user who is to be clicked on my index.html page. What is the process?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do this, you inject $modal in your controller,
Your click function looks like, you send your ID from html

```
showAdvanced = function (selectedItem) {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'your template path mean html',
        backdrop: 'static',
        controller: _userCtrl,
        windowClass: 'modal-details',
        resolve: {
            params: function () {
                return { user: selectedItem }
            }
        }
    });
    $event.stopPropagation();

};
```

You can resolve it to controller _userCtrl, it looks like

```
var _userCtrl = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'params', function ($scope, $modalInstance, params) {
  // you received your value in params, you can do it whatever you want, it will in params.user
}];
```